# algolia wordpress autocomplete

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I'm trying to tweak the WordPress plugin https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress to suit our needs. What we want to be able to do is have a search result that will load the data up in the same page.

I have my WordPress posts and its data being indexed successfully. I have added a search box to the page, and autocomplete is being fired.

Out of the box, the WordPress plugin template wraps the result in an anchor tag and assigns it the URL of the found result. When clicked, this navigates you to that post. However, what I want to do is intercept that click and load the result in the same page without navigating away.

I have removed the href from the anchor. I have also edited the supplied `autocomplete.php` template where the call to `autocomplete:selected` occurs. In there I have removed the call to navigate away by removing `window.location.href`.

Now I have two main issues.

1 - When the user clicks the search result I would like the input to be populate with the title of the item they clicked on. I added this in the `autocomplete:selected` callback by adding `$searchInput[0].value = suggestion.post_title`. Which seems to change the value of the input correctly, but as soon as I click away from the input, it is re-set back to the original typed value. So if I type 'may' and click the result 'mayonnaise', the result data can be accessed but the input returns back to 'may'. My function looks this:

```
/* Instantiate autocomplete.js */
var autocomplete = algoliaAutocomplete($searchInput[0], config, sources)
    .on('autocomplete:selected', function (e, suggestion) {
    console.log(suggestion);
    autocomplete.autocomplete.close();
});
```

2 - It seems that the autocomplete dropdown does not hide when the user clicks away. To resolve this i've had to use what I think is a bit of a nasty hack with jQuery. I was wondering if this is really required? My code just below the `autocomplete:selected` call looks like this:

```
jQuery('body').on("click", function(event){
    if (!jQuery(event.target).closest($searchInput[0]).length) {
        autocomplete.autocomplete.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some answers to my questions.

1 - In order to populate the input with the title of the selected search result I added a call to the `setVal` method of the autocomplete object. I'[m still not sure why this is required.

```
/* Instantiate autocomplete.js */
var autocomplete = algoliaAutocomplete($searchInput[0], config, sources)
    .on('autocomplete:selected', function (e, suggestion) {
        autocomplete.autocomplete.setVal(suggestion.post_title);
});
```

2 - It looks like the config of the autocomplete object uses the value of `WP_DEBUG` in order to set the `debug` value. The options available for the autocomplete component can be found here https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#options. This lead me to find that when `debug` is set to true, the autocomplete box does not hide on selection. This is to allow for easier debugging and styling of the component.